# Drawing onto ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.FeatureLayer with a specific color

Tags: c#, wpf, arcgis

I am trying to build a feature that lets the user draw onto specific features layers with a specific color. By changing FeatureLayer.Renderer all annotations on the layer change to the specified color, even the annotations that were there from a previous session. I want to be able to have the old annotations there with their specific color and new ones be drawn with their specific color (potentially different).

Here is the XAML where the map and feature layer is defined

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="GraphicsDictionary.xaml" x:Name="LineSymbolResourceDictionary"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Name="MapGrid">
    <esri:Map x:Name="MyMap">

        <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer 
            ID="StreetMapLayer" 
            x:Name="BaseMap"
            Url="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer" 
            >
        </esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer>

        <esri:FeatureLayer 
            ID="MyFeatureLayer" 
            x:Name="MyFeatureLayer"
            Url="http://123.123.123.12:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Prj/FeatureServer/0" 
            Renderer="{StaticResource BlueSimpleRenderer}"
            EndSaveEdits="drawLayer_EndSaveEdits" 
            >
        </esri:FeatureLayer>
    </esri:Map>
</Grid>
```

The resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:esriSymbols="clr-namespace:ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols;assembly=ESRI.ArcGIS.Client" 
xmlns:esri="clr-namespace:ESRI.ArcGIS.Client;assembly=ESRI.ArcGIS.Client"
x:Class="ClassName.GraphicsDictionary"
>

<esri:SimpleRenderer x:Key="BlueSimpleRenderer">
    <esri:SimpleRenderer.Symbol>
        <esriSymbols:SimpleLineSymbol x:Name="BlueLineSymbol" Color="#00007F" Width="5"/>
    </esri:SimpleRenderer.Symbol>
</esri:SimpleRenderer>
```

The C# Code for drawing:

```
public void StartDrawing(FeatureLayer inputLayer, string inputColorInHex)
{
    MyMap.Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Pen;
    //Below's the color that might be different from the original renderer
    SimpleRenderer newRend= new SimpleRenderer 
    { 
       Symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(inputColorInHex), 12)        
    };
    inputLayer.Renderer = newRend as IRenderer;
    MyDrawObject.DrawMode = ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.DrawMode.Freehand;
    MyDrawObject.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The renderer applies to all features (graphics) in the layer so if you want to use a renderer you could use a unique value renderer and set different styles for different attribute values though this implies that you know what values to use when defining the colours. Similarly if you want to control the colours based on a range of values then you can use a class breaks renderer.

In your situation though you may just want to set specific symbols for features since a symbol will override the renderer. You just apply the symbol to the graphic in order for it to be used. e.g.

```
var markerSym = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Symbology.SimpleMarkerSymbol
{
    Style = Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Symbology.SimpleMarkerStyle.Diamond,
    Color = Colors.Green,
    Size = 18
};

var pointGraphic = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Layers.Graphic(point, markerSym);

graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(pointGraphic);
```